# ImportError: cannot import name 'variable name'

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a problem, when I try to import two variables that store the results of two SQL queries, PyCharm tells me :

> "ImportError: cannot import name 'nb_panelN2' from
> 'Models.Requetesfrontend'"

I don't understand why ?

**SQL Query (from Requetesfrontend)**

```
import pymysql as sql

def produced_panels(month):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = 'SELECT COUNT(panelname) ' \
              'FROM panels ' \
              'WHERE month(datecreation) = %s '
              % month
        cursor.execute(sql)
        print (cursor.fetchall())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Panels in N1
    nb_panelN1 = produced panels('month(now())-1')

    #Panels in N2
    nb_panelN2 = produced panels('month(now())-2')
```

**Graph (from the graph file)**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from Requetesfrontend import nb_panelN1, nb_panelN2


#X of graph
x = [
    ["Number of panels"],
    ["N-2", "N-1", "N"]
]

# Number of panels in N1
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(
    x=x,
    y=[nb_panelN2[0]['COUNT(nompanneau)']], 0],
    name='N1',
    text=[nb_panelN1[0]['COUNT(nompanneau)']],
)])
```

Thank you

Comment: The entire point of `if __name__ == '__main__'` is that the code inside that if statement DOESN'T happen if the module is imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `nb_panelN1` outside of `if __name__ == "__main__"` as @TARS mentioned.

Also, you need to define `nb_panelN2` since it is not defined anywhere.

In **SQL Query (from Requetesfrontend)**

```
import pymysql as sql

def produced_panels(month):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = 'SELECT COUNT(panelname) ' \
              'FROM panels ' \
              'WHERE month(datecreation) = %s '
              % month
        cursor.execute(sql)
        print (cursor.fetchall())


nb_panelN1 = produced panels('month(now())-1')
# nb_panelN2 = .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Because nb_panelN1 and nb_panelN2 are only created `if __name__ == "__main__"` and that is not the case as it is not the file that is being executed. Get the variable initializations outside the name main condition and it should work